# selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable sending text to First name field using Selenium Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

Through Selenium, I try to enter the username on one popular site, but, for some reason I do not understand, this does not work. Everything opens, a click occurs on the desired input field, but immediately after that an error appears when trying to enter text.
Here is my code:

```
webdriverDir = "./chromedriver.exe"  
home_url = 'https://appleid.apple.com/account/'

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=webdriverDir)
browser.get(home_url)
elem = browser.find_element_by_id("firstNameInput")
elem.click()
elem.send_keys('namename')
time.sleep(5)
```

I also tried to change the solution to this:

```
browser.find_element_by_id("firstNameInput").send_keys("namename")
```

But it also does not work. I can’t understand what’s the matter. 
Also tried through `xpath`, `class_name` and `css_selector`. The result was either the same or the element was simply not detected. Although everything was copied from element code from console.

Error Code:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
```

Where could there be a mistake? Or can it be the site itself?

Answer (score 0):

The element with `firstNameInput` id is not an input and it's a custom tag and your `send-keys` commands can not access that element.

what you have to do is, access the input present in the parent element.

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#firstNameInput input").send_keys('hello')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To send a *character sequence* to the **First name** field you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://appleid.apple.com/account/")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "first-name-input#firstNameInput input"))).send_keys("haruhi")
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://appleid.apple.com/account/")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='form-label' and normalize-space()='First name']//preceding::input[1]"))).send_keys("haruhi")
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: create_your_apple_id]